# Entertainment Area is cooling required with this setup? Where to position fans?

Tags: exhaust-fan, cooling, television, home-theater, intake-fan

I am getting my entertainment area setup and I wanted to get opinions on where I should install intake/exhaust fans and if it would even be required.

Within my "nitch" I am going to have an amplifier, Xbox, AV Receiver, and potentially a center speaker or BlueRay player. (*not sure just yet*).

I am skeptical if any sort of cooling will even be needed considering my setup but I am honestly not sure. My question is:

- Would cooling even be required considering my setup?
- If I did add cooling *(required or not)* where should I setup the box fans at?
- I want to make sure the area stays cool *(i.e: doesnt over heat)*

I am attaching pictures to give more insight on my setup. Also below are a few notes.

- *Fireplace is electric*.
- *The entertainment area will have the devices squeezed in close to one another but nothing is technically "sealed off"*
- *There are two access panels on each side of the fireplace so there is a small 1 inch gap on each side which allow fresh air in.*

Thanks ahead of time :)

[image: Fireplace]
[image: Nitch]
[image: Overall]

Comment: Well, first test is how hot that space gets when the fire has been on for several hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After months of testing I can confirm there is no issues. The area contains enough hollow space for the heat to rise and disperse with no form of overheating.